# Dependency Management in multi-module projects - How to handle provided dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have a multi-module Maven project that contains of EARs and JARs. I try to centralise the dependencyManagement in the parent/module pom of the multi-module project.

The problem: For the EARs, I have a list of dependencies that should be marked `provided` because they are provided by the Java EE container.

In the JARs, the dependencies should *not* be provided because then, they are "lost" in the transitive dependency resolution: If `A.jar` depends on `B.jar` and `B.jar` has a provided dependency on `C.jar`, `C.jar` will be eliminated from the dependency tree of `A.jar` because provided dependencies are not transitive.

Now I cannot set the `scope` depending on the `packaging`, so I get the impression that the (complete) centralisation of the dependencyManagement is not possible. Am I right?

Comment: Define all dependencies in dependencyManagement without scope. Define the scope in the module where you use them...

Comment: @khmarbaise I do not quite understand. When I build the EAR, I need to filter out the dependencies that are provided by the container. I need dependencyManagement for that because I want to filter out some of the transitive dependencies (the EAR itself only has some ejb artifacts as direct dependencies).

Comment: We are doing something I think is similar with our OSGi container. We have created a separate `provided-dependencies` module that has all 3rd party deps that are provided by the container in scope 'compile'. The jars we deploy in the container (similar to your EARs) then depend on this module with scope 'provided'. Our standalone tool jars do not use the `provided-dependencies` module at all, and neither do they depend on any of the deployed modules because provided deps are not inherited. Hope this helps somehow.